# Response based xml -- PHP

Tags: php, xml

I submit a value to the Server.. something like this

abc.php

```
<?php
$input = "some value"
//Some functions
```

The above generates some unique response say 111

Now i need to upload a xml based on this response something like this

```
$xml='<?xml version= "1.0 .....>
<id>111</id>(this id should be dynamic and based on the response)'
?>
```

this xml is in above php file(abc.php)

How can i do this?

Comment: @marc i haven't accomplished anything ..as i do not have idea of how to create a dynamic xml based on the response.

Comment: there is a script here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534695/trouble-inserting-variable-as-my-url-in-php-fopen/7538240#7538240 see[Sep 24 at 9:51] that retrieves data from mysql, it brings data back to web page as xml and also you can save them as a xml file too. You can remove some parts of the code and keep only the functionality that you need.

Comment: I think the emphasis on @Marc's question is what have you *tried*, not so much what have you accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in your comment, this might help you

**Alternative A**: Write a XML file from the abc.php script

```
<?php

// Gets a value from a URL GET parameter.
$value = $_GET[ 'value' ];

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<doc>
    <id>$value</id>
</doc>
XML;

// The location of the XML that is about to be generated.
$xmlPath = 'output.xml';
if ( file_put_contents( $xmlPath, $xml ) === false )
{
    trigger_error( 'There was an error trying to write the XML file (check permissions)', E_USER_NOTICE );
}
```

**Alternative B**: Output an XML response from script upload.php using abc.php

abc.php

```
<?php
function doSomethingHere()
{
    return rand();
}
```

upload.php

```
<?php
// Include your PHP library.
require 'abc.php';
// Set the correct Content type to instruct browsers to treat the document as XML file.
header( 'Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' );
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<doc>
    <id><?php echo doSomethingHere(); ?></id>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an script **abc.php**

```
<?php

// Gets a value from a URL GET parameter.
$value = $_GET[ 'value' ];

echo $value;
```

Then you could have a second script **upload.php** like this

```
<?php

// Retrieves the response from /abc.php
$urlResponse = file_get_contents( 'http://localhost/abc.php?value=foobar' );

header( 'Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' );

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>', PHP_EOL;
echo '<doc>', PHP_EOL;
echo '<id>', $urlResponse, '</id>', PHP_EOL;
echo '</doc>', PHP_EOL;
```

The script upload.php **retrieves the response** (using the file_get_contents function) of the abc script and **generates an XML output**.

More info: http://www.php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: Hii..thanks a lot...but what i want to do is have a single php file with XML in it and one field of the XML should be dynamically updated based on the response to one of the function...